# What happened to /etc/apt/apt.conf?

Tags: 11.04, apt, proxy

I was browsing through the apt folder to try my proxy settings and I was unable to find the apt.conf file in Ubuntu 11.04. Is there any alternative file for it?

Adding proxy settings to 99-synaptic in apt.conf.d does not help as it gets overwritten everytime I restart the system.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file is still read if it exists.  The apt configuration provided by packages is installed as separate files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` so that it can be added and updated independent of any local changes you make in the main configuration file.

So if you have local configuration changes, just create the file.

Comment: so, lets say, i want a global proxy config that i want to add for cli and software centre (network proxy settings doesnt work for both, a well known fact!), where do i add that? previously adding proxy settings to apt.conf solved all problems!

Comment: Crrate a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` that has your addition.  This has been available for several releases.  It is a cleaner way of doing this kind of change.

Comment: As I said, create the `apt.conf` file and add your settings there.  It works identically to previous releases.

Answer (score 9):

Just add the following to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and the problem is solved: `sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf` then add this to the first line:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy_address:8080/";
```

Comment: Solved my problem!! Thanks! Fighting it for days.....

Comment: resolved my issue too.