# Apt-get update with an @ in password error

Tags: apt, proxy, special-characters

I want to update ubuntu 11.04 throught `apt-get`.
So I added the following lines in `apt.conf`

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.netport/

export http_proxy=http://deepak:Deepak@123@12.1.1.1:3128
```

My question is: how do I insert special characters to a username or password?

For instance: my password for proxy is Deepak@123 and it is getting an error.

Comment: Er... is that *really* your password?

Comment: You can export proxy settings in `.bashrc`. In `apt.conf` you have to use [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34666/what-happened-to-etc-apt-apt-conf/43218#43218)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to `escape` special characters. So place a `\` in front of the `@` like so:

```
export http_proxy=http://deepak:Deepak\@123@12.1.1.1:3128
```

Alernatively you can also use `%40`.

Comment: Full list of HTML character codes http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html

Comment: An online encoder / decoder : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: inside /etc/apt/apt.conf %40 works

Comment: URL encoding from here:  
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp  
worked for me, see here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282186/apt-get-behind-proxy-special-characters-in-username-and-password

Tested on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 4):

Click on

1. Dash home
2. Search for **System Settings**
3. Select **Network**
4. Select **Network Proxy**
5. Select **Manual** method
6. Set you proxy and port

Kudos You are Done if you set right

Answer (score 4):

If your password or username contains `@` you can percent-encode (also [referred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as URL encoding) it as `%40` in the proxy url. For more special characters see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**Even more simple and Reliable!**

**General Syntax:**

```
sudo {http,https,ftp}_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_url/_proxyip>:<port>/ wget --timeout=5 --no-check-certificate http://<website_url>
```

**Example:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo {http,https,ftp}_proxy=http://username:password-123@proxy.example.com:6050/ wget --timeout=5 --no-check-certificate http://google.com
```

**{http,https,ftp}_proxy**   -> http, https, ftp urls. Seperated by comma.

**--timeout=5**  -> Connection to keep alive in seconds.

**-no-check-certificate**  -> Ignore SSL / Certificate Verification.

**--spider**  -> If you want to test the connectivity without downloading the file.

**Notes:**

**Online Converter:**

Replace special characters with its equivalent hexadecimal unicode. 
For a list of unicodes refer the website [https://unicode-table.com](http://unicodelookup.com) (or) [http://unicodelookup.com](https://unicode-table.com)

**Local Converter using Python:**

**Reference:** conversion of password "p@s#w:E" to unicode will be as follows,

```
@ = %40
$ = %24
# = %23
: = %3A
p@s#w:E = p%40s%23w%3AE
```

**Input:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# python -c "import sys, urllib as enc; print enc.quote_plus(sys.argv[1])" "p@s#w:E"
```

**Output:**

```
p%40s%23w%3AE
```