# proxy authentication in system settings but with a twist

Tags: proxy, system

We have a password policy that enforces the users to use special characters in their passwords. Hence some passwords will be Gt4@gj#k for example.

Now to specify the system wide proxy settings (Why isn't this done more intuitively like for instance the way it was done in synaptic; and why is synaptic not included by default anymore either...) you have to use username:password@host in the host field for authenticating proxies.

Our problem no is that some passwords have the @ sign in them so it breaks this simple system.

How can I employ a system wide proxy to work with apt and the system updater that allows real world passwords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a program asks you to enter the proxy configuration as an http URL, you will need to follow the conventions for structuring URLs.

And that means you can not include an `@` character in the user name or password components **unless you encode them**.  Characters can be encoded in URLs as a percent sign followed by the hexadecimal representation of the code point.

So for the password `Gt4@gj#k`, you could represent it as `Gt4%40gj%23k` (the hash symbol is used to delimit the fragment portion of a URL, so it is best to encode it as well).

Comment: Thanks, it seem to have worked for most application. Yet some like apt does not work still.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below URL

Duplicate question search before asking a question.

[Apt-get with special character](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60217/apt-get-update-with-an-in-password-error)