# Proxy Settings in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apt-get update with an @ in password error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60217/apt-get-update-with-an-in-password-error)

My system is running under corporate network.

I need to set proxy server settings. But I am not sure if the format below is correct or not. I need a solution for this. I am using 12.04.

```
http://hbi\MFazil:password@123@proxy.server.com:8080/
```

`hbi` is domain name. I need to login using the prefix `hbi`. I am using `@` in my password. Both `hbi\` and `@` in the password will affect the syntax.

Comment: You really should ask your corporate network administrator about this - if it is your personnel PC they may not want you to connect it to their network for a variety of reasons, if the PC is supplied by them then this should already be done for you...