# Proxy setting in terminal but my password consist '@'

Tags: password, proxy

I was googling about proxy setting in terminal.

Example answer:

> For your apt-get to work, you should edit your apt config file:
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
> ```
>
> And add `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyhost:port/";`
>
> The syntax shown above should be strictly followed.
>
> This configuration may fail if your username or password has an '@' in it. You can also add proxy configuration for other protocols such as FTP.

My problem is how when my password consist '@' character, but not change my password

Thanks.

Comment: When you use escape characters, you should _escape it_. This is done by using single quotes `'` around that character.

Comment: Anther duplicate candidate[Apt-get update with an @ in password error](http://askubuntu.com/q/60217/107450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ is %40 when escaped. What happens if you use that instead of @?

Comment: thanks for answer, i found that i just use '\' before special character