# Setting proxy in Ubuntu terminal - proxy having special characters

Tags: 12.04, networking, command-line, sudo, proxy

I am trying to set proxy for a ubuntu server 12.04. Our proxy user name contains in the format:

```
CompanyName\UserName
```

and Password like:

```
$test
```

I tried to set proxy like this:

```
export http_proxy='http://CompanyName\UserName:$test@proxy.company.com:8080/'
```

But when I run any commands which require internet, like `sudo apt-get` etc, still I am getting error, `407 Proxy Authentication Required`.

As far as I am aware the above command should be correct. I searched lot and got above syntax, but not sure how to deal with proxy username containing like above.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: You just need to escape the special characters see this question: [Apt-get update with an @ in password error](http://askubuntu.com/q/60217/107450)

Comment: @WarrenHill Thanks that worked fine :) I escaped $ to %24, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sudo does not preserve your environment variable. See the following link for an answer on how to configure sudo to do it:

https://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables

Comment: Yeah that issue ok, but I am worried about that `\` character in username field which is not accepting.