# problem with downloading software packages through proxy server wifi

Tags: installation, 12.10, proxy, software-updater

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10,but during installation I ignored update software package.after installing Ubuntu successfully  now whenever I'm updating through software updater it is showing failed to download repository information. 
I'm having proxy server wifi connection.
please help me to overcome the problem.
Thank you

Comment: Try `apt-get -f install` and then try software updater once again

Answer (score 1):

To set your proxy settings, click on the gear icon on the top-right corner of your screen. Click on "System Settings" and then on Network. You can see the "Network Proxy" button to your letf. Change the "method" to "Manual" and type the proxy-address and port-no for all the relevant fields(HTTP proxy, HTTPS proxy, FTP proxy and socks proxy).

If you need to authenticate your login, i.e. you need to add a user-name and password, you need to edit the `etc/apt/apt.conf` file as given in the answer by user17823 [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34666/what-happened-to-etc-apt-apt-conf/43218#43218).

I have made a script to do this. You can download this from [my blog](http://www.thelittleican.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-set-proxy-authentication-for.html).

This should set the proxy settings and now you should be able to use your internet to download packages.