# How can I disable apt-get autoremove?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I added a bad ppa to my system and now I need to do manual package removing/downgrading.

The issue is that I enabled `apt-get autoremove` a while ago and removing a package to later replace it/downgrade threaten to uninstall perfectly working apps from my system.

I came across a [solution to disable apt-get autoremove](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58228/78806) but for some reason I am not sure it applies to my configuration (trusty) as my `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove` looks very different from the sample:

```
APT::Get::AutomaticRemove "0";
APT::Get::HideAutoRemove "1";
```

Here what my 01autoremove looks like:

```
APT
{
  NeverAutoRemove
  {
    "^firmware-linux.*";
    "^linux-firmware$";
  };

  VersionedKernelPackages
  {
    # linux kernels
    "linux-image";
    "linux-headers";
<snip>
```

I really need to disable the autoremove feature so I can start to fix my package version with a clear mind and fearing that some other related package/app got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

From an [answer to another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/34668/432978):

> "The /etc/apt/apt.conf file is still read if it exists. The apt configuration provided by packages is installed as separate files in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ so that it can be added and updated independent of any local changes you make in the main configuration file.
>
> So if you have local configuration changes, just create the file."

Follows that if you drop the lines you mention into `/etc/apt/apt.conf` you should be good to go.  It worked for me.

Comment: Instead of copying another answer it is better to flag the answer as duplicate.