# what is apt.conf in simple and understandable slang?

Tags: apt, aptitude

I have gone though `man apt.conf`. I feel the information there is quite overwhelming and difficult to understand for beginners moving to Ubuntu/Debinan Platforms.

Could some one explain in simple english what is the use of this file and how it can benefit an `apt` user.

Further this file seems be not setup on my machine - so I think it's not required for normal usage, but I am trying to understand advanced usage. so want to dig in to it.

```
ll /etc/apt/apt.conf
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/apt.conf': No such file or directory
```

Edit:
I feel trying to understand the `apt conf` part on a whole makes sense as every thing should be some or the other way related.
On going to `/etc/apt` and doing an `ls -l`

```
/etc/apt$ ll
total 72
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Aug 28 23:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 144 root root 12288 Sep  1 15:53 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep  1 15:53 apt.conf.d/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr  9 15:51 auth.conf.d/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr  9 15:51 preferences.d/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3412 Aug 31 20:35 sources.list
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 31 20:34 sources.list.d/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3410 Aug 31 20:35 sources.list.save
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 14771 Aug 28 23:46 trusted.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8497 Aug 27 01:28 trusted.gpg~
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 28 23:46 trusted.gpg.d/
```

Evey thing here is understandable after bit of digging. Except for `apt.conf.d/` (and  `auth.conf.d/`, which seems to be empty and I am not bothered about this in this Q).

Now on entering - `apt.conf.d/` and doing `ll` you see bunch of more files -

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d$ ll
total 96
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  1 15:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug 28 23:46 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49 Aug 18 01:22 00aptitude
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Aug 18 01:21 00trustcdrom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  630 Apr  9 15:51 01autoremove
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1349 Sep  1 15:53 01autoremove-kernels
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Apr  9 15:51 01-vendor-ubuntu
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  168 Aug 31 20:32 10periodic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  108 Apr  2 16:55 15update-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   85 Apr  2 16:55 20archive
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  168 Aug 31 20:32 20auto-upgrades
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  243 Dec 16  2009 20dbus
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1040 Mar 12 18:50 20packagekit
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  114 Jun  5 18:43 20snapd.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2592 Jan 18  2020 50appstream
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2164 Feb  9  2019 50apt-file.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  625 Oct  7  2019 50command-not-found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5459 Apr 14 04:07 50unattended-upgrades
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  435 Jan 18  2020 60icons
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  251 Jan 18  2020 60icons-hidpi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  182 Aug  3  2019 70debconf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   32 Aug 28 12:34 99synaptic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  305 Apr  2 16:55 99update-notifier
```

**So through this Q, I am looking for answers regarding the significance of `apt.conf` and the set of files in `apt.conf.d/`** - what kind of configurations does these files enable ( and of course `man apt.conf` is not quite understandable at least for beginners)

Second Edit following user535733 response -
How are the files in the `apt.conf.d` named. Do they follow some naming convention that simplifies understanding what config aspects go where.

Comment: I am an experienced user and I have never looked at, let alone modified, the contents of `apt.conf` (which has probably been replaced by the conf files under `apt.conf.d`). I appreciate your curiosity but it would probably be more productive to have a look at other man pages.

Comment: @User24601 [What happened to /etc/apt/apt.conf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34666/what-happened-to-etc-apt-apt-conf) does not give a holistic or indepth view in to apt conf aspects.

Comment: nor does it have anything to with the price of fish...

Comment: As `Jos` pointed out, `man apt.conf` does not need to be understandable for beginners. Explaining everything in there is not a suitable question for askubuntu, please give us a real-world problem you have with it or at least on specific part that you don't understand.

Comment: "*looking for answers regarding the significance of apt.conf*" is too vague to be answerable. It's like asking about the "significance" of a bicycle or of rain. Significance is in the eye of user, and each user may see something different.

Comment: regret your -1 , but sof and askubuntu is everthing about learning... don't think there are upper bounds set here :-)) More over this Q show research and exploration effort. So it's more fit here than else where on the planet

Answer (score 4):

**[I]n simple english what is the use of [apt.conf] and how it can benefit an apt user.**

- The configuration files (apt.conf and apt.conf.d/*) allow users to customize how various apt functions work. Common customizations are for local proxy servers and for the Unattended Upgrades feature.
- Users benefit from fine-grained control *if they need it*. Most users don't need it. Most users never need to touch these files. The default settings work for most users.
- Some referenced files may not exist on your system. That's okay. Different config files are placed/removed in the apt.conf.d/ directory as-needed by various pacakges (or by you). That's why the apt.conf.d/ directory exists - so applications can make changes without editing a single master config file.
- Files in the apt.conf.d/ directory are loaded in alphanumerical order. That's why the file names in that directory include numbers. The order is important: If two files try to change the same setting, the last file loaded wins. (If you discover two files trying to change the same setting differently, please file a bug report against those two packages so the developers can evaluate and fix the conflict.)

Comment: this is great - so `apt config` reads and processes every file in the `apt.conf.d` dir. Does the file names them self have any convention though they are treated similarly by the apt conf

Comment: Please edit your Question above to include follow up questions. AskUbuntu uses a Question/Answer format. It's not a threaded forum. Edited to explain the naming convention.